# Stored procedure expects parameter but parameter is actually supplied?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

I need to know why I am still getting this error

> Stored procedure expects parameter which was not supplied

But I am actually sending this parameter.

The stored procedure in the database looks like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SVC_BUSCA_MEDIO_LANDING
     (@rut VARCHAR) 
AS   
BEGIN  
    SELECT utm_source   
    FROM landing_formulario   
    WHERE rut = @rut    
END
```

And my .net code:

```
string result = string.Empty;
string connString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["StPazWeb"].ToString();
string SVC_BUSCA_MEDIO_LANDING = "SVC_BUSCA_MEDIO_LANDING"; 

using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connString))
{
    connection.Open();

    try
    {
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(SVC_BUSCA_MEDIO_LANDING);
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        command = new SqlCommand(command.CommandText, connection);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rut", rut);

        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            result = (string)reader["utm_source"];                    
        }
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        throw new Exception("Oops!." + ex.Message);
    }
}

return result.ToString();
```

Any idea what can be happening?

Comment: These lines do nothing because you're assigning command variable again: SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(SVC_BUSCA_MEDIO_LANDING);
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

Comment: you don't have to initialize everything in your `SqlCommand` via the constructors. Use the `SqlConnection` overload to initialize your SqlCommand, then set the `CommandType` and `CommandText` properties as part of an object construction syntax expression: `var cmd = new SqlCommand(SVC_BUSCA_MEDIO_LANDING, connection) { CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure };`

Comment: One MAJOR problem here is that you have defined your procedure parameter as a varchar but did not define the size. Do you know what the default is for a parameter? Do you know that varchar with no size will use different default sizes based on where is used? ALWAYS specify the size. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length

Comment: related - don't use [addwithvalue](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/)

Answer (score 0):

For some reason you create the command twice, with the second instantiation replacing the first, however on the second one you don't set the command type, and as a result your parameter is being ignored.

Try:

```
SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
command.CommandText = SVC_BUSCA_MEDIO_LANDING;
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rut", rut);
```

Answer (score -2):

You're using:

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(SVC_BUSCA_MEDIO_LANDING);
```

but you're reseting the command at:

```
command = new SqlCommand(command.CommandText, connection);
```

Try instead:

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
command.CommandText = "SVC_BUSCA_MEDIO_LANDING";
command = new SqlCommand(command.CommandText, connection);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rut", rut);
```

Comment: while that is indeed an issue, it's merely a way for the OP to get around a perceived inability to set the `SqlConnection` and the `CommandText` via the constructor.

Comment: @JoshE you're right, thanks for the feedback. Hope the OP gets an valid answer.